# Part `<` and part `&lt;` in one NSData

Tags: ios, soap, wsdl, touchxml

I'm accessing http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php using code generated by http://sudzc.com

The SOAP message is being sent and I can see the returned message and here I've a screenshot for the `NSData` that I print out in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Wired thing is, symbol `<` shows up correct at the beginning, but then it's `&lt;`.

Can anyone suggest how can I fix this?

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the WSDL for this web service, it actually returns a xml in the html body part.

```
<message name="NDFDgenByDayResponse">
   <part name="dwmlByDayOut" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
```

So that respond is actually correct and I will just have to parse it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can simply apply an existing encoding like how the handy function `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` exists, but if an existing solution doesn't exist, you can always use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

I would try and look around for an encoding converter first though, because I see that `&lt;` isn't the only entity in your text. `&gt;` exists as well.